# UA String failed,prompt Invalid Device type

Tags: cobalt

We set it "TPV_linux", but we found UA String failed.

We checked the underscore "*" and found that it was half-width "*" rather than full-size "＿", so it should not fail.

We do not understand what caused this, can you help to check?

[image]

Comment: For questions about YouTube certification please refer to your YouTube account manager.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore and some other characters are replaced in function ***Sanitize()*** when the User Agent string is created in ***UserAgentStringFactory::CreateUserAgentString()***.

Please, check file **cobalt/network/user_agent_string_factory.cc** for more details, but comments in the source code suggest that these chars are reserved:

```
struct SanitizeReplacements {
  const char* replace_chars;
  const char* replace_with;
} kSanitizeReplacements[] = {
  { ",", u8"\uFF0C" },  // fullwidth comma
  { "_", u8"\u2E0F" },  // paragraphos
  { "/", u8"\u2215" },  // division slash
  { "(", u8"\uFF08" },  // fullwidth left paren
  { ")", u8"\uFF09" },  // fullwidth right paren
};
```